# Multiple microphone recording

Tags: audio, microphone

I want to record from multiple microphones into separate USB microphones on a Raspberry Pi.

Is this possible?
Do I need to buy some sort of USB sound card?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a USB from analog audio converter for analog microphones, but it is easier and probably cheaper to just use USB microphones. They will already include the converter part.